# Camel: How to include an ampersand as data in a URI (NOT as a delimiter)?

Tags: java, apache-camel

(Camel 2.9.2)

Very simple use case, but I can't seem to find the answer. My code boils down to this:

```
String user = "user";
String password = "foo&bar";

String uri = "smtp://hostname:25?username=" + user +
    "&password=" + password + 
    "&to=somthing@something.com"; // etc. You get the idea

from("seda:queue:myqueue").to(uri);
```

Camel throws a ResolveEndpointFailedException with "Unknown parameters=[{bar=null}]."

If I try "foo%26bar," I get the same result.

If I try "foo&amp;bar" camel responds with "Unknown parameters=[{amp;bar=null}]."

I tried using URISupport to create the URI. It escapes the & to %26, and then I get "Unknown parameters=[{bar=null}]" again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

As from Camel 2.11 you could use raw syntax

For instance:

`.to("ftp:joe@myftpserver.com?password=RAW(se+re?t&23)&binary=true"`

> In the above example, we have declare the password value as raw, and
>   the actual password would be as typed, eg se+re?t&23

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/How+do+I+configure+endpoints

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the password as part of the authority of the uri, eg in the front.
Also the & should be escaped to %26, but there was a bug in Camel that didnt parse the escaped value to well. Try 2.10 when its out.

Comment: Is there a JIRA for the & bug.  I'm running into a problem using %26 in version 2.13.0

Answer (score 0):

The `RAW()` syntax works, yet it is Camel-proprietary syntax. In our usecase it burdened following processing of URI.

We used alternative solution: component configured as using raw URIs (`Component.useRawUri() == true`). Component parameters are then simply once encoded (`foo%26bar`) and pass through Camel without change. I consider this solution better as percent-sign encoding is standard way of expressing sensitive characters.